# Example that needs explanation

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm in the state of chaotic about the following sentences can you guide me through proper use of them. Kindly help me either restructure the sentence or clearly state the right form of verb, thanks in advance

1. Ali rather likes to know more secure and (protective OR protected) layers
2. However, the rise of the new technologies and modern system (invite OR invites) the challenges by means of...
3. He studied the effect of torque on the system that may (destabilizes OR destabilize) system or even (creates OR create) devastating hazards.

Comment: we don't do proof reading. focus your question to one specific problem, although these have all been asked before

Comment: @vectory, if these are previously asked can you share the link?

Comment: And here we have the big problem with ELU.SE. How ***DO*** we find answers to questions like these? Our millions of answers are searchable, but what should we search for?

Comment: Aside from how to search for such things, which is a good question, this inquiry is simply trivial for native speakers, and as such is arguably immediately off-topic for EL&U. I would say it should be moved to (or repeated on) the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange.

Comment: @JohnLawler I suggested, in an answer to a meta question https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13266/whats-the-average-score-for-questions-in-2019/13270#13270, that the site develop some typical questions with links to good answers. Keyword searches don’t work well enough to target answers, nor do they reveal some of the great material here.

Comment: @Xanne That's one of the reasons why I made a [list of my answers on various topics](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13492/15299). Of course, you have to know enough grammar to look in the right place, and use the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ali rather likes to know more secure and protective layers.
- However, the rise of the new technologies and modern system invites the challenges by means of...
- He studied the effect of torque on the system that may destabilize system or even create devastating hazards.

These sentences are pretty poor structures even once correctly selected.

- Ali likes to know more secure and protective layers.
- However, the rise of new technologies and modern systems invite
  challenges by means of...
- He studied the effect of torque on a system that may destabilize the
  system or even create devastating hazards as a result.

Comment: Thank you @RustyUK, can you just elaborate on why they are poorly structured?

Comment: Likes to have, please.

Comment: @Shane I gave examples of better structure underneath for you.